# javascript image popup on text mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want images to popup when I mouse over some HTML text, using JavaScript and jQuery. There are multiple lines and each line should popup a different image.
I don't mean an actual popup window, just the image popping out or blowing up in the screen.

So if my html code looks something like:

```
<p id="item1">item1 text</p>
<p id="item2">item2 text</p>
<p id="item3">item3 text</p>
```

When I mouse over the text “item1 text” on the HTML page, I want an image called “image1” to popup on the text. I also want to the popup to include some text above the picture. When I move the mouse pointer off of that item1 text, the popup should go away.  Likewise, when I mouse over “item2 text”, image2 should pop up.

How do I do this using JavaScript, then how would I use jQuery to do it better?

I am a complete JavaScript and jQuery novice, sorry in advance for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What do you mean by 'each line'? Each `div` should produce a different pop-up, or each line of text contained within a `div` should produce a different pop-up?

Comment: each line of text should produce a different image popup. so each paragraph tag.

Comment: The problem is I know little about js and jquery. so I was thinking something like $('#item1").show() . I know this is wrong. How do i associate the mouseover action with the image1 that i want to popup. does css do some of this?

Comment: That depends on how the images are associated with the relevant `p` tag; by `id`, by `class`, by `data-*`, or other, attribute? By their index position within another element? Are they nested within the `p` itself..? (If they were nested within, or followed, the `p` element then this could be done with pure CSS.)

Answer (score 4):

Hi I found this excellent tutorial: [jQuery for Absolute Beginners](http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/), he used the `<a>` tag for the html code, here's how he did it: 
http://jsfiddle.net/k2E7W/2/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the excellent [jQuery plugin Powertip](http://stevenbenner.github.com/jquery-powertip/) which will save you lots of hazzle. Typically, such mouseover / mouseout - things are kind of tricky regarding cross browser compatibility and positioning.

Code would then look something like

```
$('#element')
    .data('powertipjq', $('<p>Some text</p><img src="yourImage.png" />'));
    .powerTip({
        placement: 'e',
        mouseOnToPopup: true
    });
```

Comment: Thanks David. but i would prefer to do this with pure javascript and some jquery. I am trying to learn too.

Comment: So it's basically mouseover / mouseout, take a look in the source of powerTip-